# Getting an Error with Time (Java)

Tags: java, debugging, compiler-errors

```
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.conversion(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
    at testing.thetest.toMilitary(thetest.java:14)
    at testing.apples.main(apples.java:6)
```

I have two classes, one is apples, one is thetest.

APPLES CODE:

```
package testing;

public class apples{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        thetest thetestOb = new thetest();
        System.out.println(thetestOb.toMilitary());
        thetestOb.setTime(13, 27, 6);
        System.out.println(thetestOb.toMilitary());
    }
}
```

THETEST CODE:

```
package testing;
public class thetest{
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int second;

    public void setTime(int h, int m, int s){
        hour = ((h >= 0 && h < 24) ? h : 0);
        minute = ((m >= 0 && m < 60) ? m : 0);
        second = ((s >= 0 && s < 60) ? s : 0);
    }

    public String toMilitary(){
        return String.format("%O2d:%O2d:%O2d", hour, minute, second);
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain why I'm getting these errors? I'm a beginner with Java and I'm learning off of video tutorials. I made sure the code was EXACTLY the same, yet I got this error. Someone else had the same problem. Please help.

Comment: You didn't add the error message which tells you why this happens. An `O` is not an `0`.

Comment: That was the error message... It had no X's, and the guy wrote O in the tutorial, not 0.

Comment: @Code123 I sincerely recommend ignoring video tutorials whose likely primary objective is garnering advertisement impressions rather than teaching. I heartily suggest the venerable Java Trail tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are using the letter "O" instead of number zero(0).

```
 public String toMilitary(){
        return String.format("%O2d:%O2d:%O2d", hour, minute, second);
    }
```

Change them to 0, it will work.

Comment: Does not work? It worked for me because thats your only problem.
run:
00:00:00
13:27:06
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: It does work, I thanked you for it.

Comment: Then, can you please select my answer as the correct one. Thank you

Comment: It said that I had to wait a minute, so I just wrote the comment and did not bother. Anyways, here you go.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And make sure you capitalize first letters of your class names. This is a bad coding practice ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, initialize all the variable.

```
package testing;
public class thetest{
    private int hour = 0;
    private int minute = 0;
    private int second = 0;

    public void setTime(int h, int m, int s){
        hour = ((h >= 0 && h < 24) ? h : 0);
        minute = ((m >= 0 && m < 60) ? m : 0);
        second = ((s >= 0 && s < 60) ? s : 0);
    }

    public String toMilitary(){
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
    }
}
```

Because if you dont initialize the instance variables, on the first call, `toMilitary()`, hour, minute and second have no value in them at all.
You are only setting value the second time around.

And yes, those will be `0` (zeros) not `O`s. `%O2d` is not a Java syntax. It wont even compile.